# returning JSON from javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to learn how to replace callback functions with async and await. After two days I have the following working in that it will write the json to the console from **inside the function.**

```
const requestRoster = async ()=> {
    const response = await fetch('/testing/getRoster.php', {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    const json = await response.json()
    console.log(json); // writes the array json to the console
    return json; //apparently returns a pending promise
}

﻿
```

However, when I say

```
$roster = requestRoster();
console.log ($roster); // writes Promise{<pending}> to the console
​
```

The console reports

> Promise {}
>   When I expand this line, I see:

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(64)
```

and Array(64) contains the data I want.

Obviously I'm a bit lost here.  Apparently the function requestRoster() is returning a pending promise. 
What I want is for it to return the Array(64). So, where am I going wrong? I simply want requestRoster() to return the Array(64)

Thanks,

Comment: It can't return the result, its async. You need to await the promise.

Comment: `$roster = await requestRoster();`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Thanks gents,  I have a lot to think about and learn

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `async` keyword the function automatically returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

And the `await` keyword is used to wait for the promise to resolve.

You can easily do it like that:

```
$roster = await requestRoster();
```

But note that this can only be done in a function that is `async` itself. If you want to use it on top level you can use a IIFE (Immediately-Invoked Function Expression) like this:

```
(async () => {
  $roster = await requestRoster();
  // do something with $roster here
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

An `async` declared function returns a promise, even if you return a simple value. If you return such a value it gets wrapped into a already resolved Promise which you can read out the known ways.

If you are in another async function, you can await it.

```
$roster = await requestRoster();
```

In a simple function or arrow function you can use the promise methods.

```
requestRooster().then( (roster) => { /* do something with rooster*/ } );
```

Answer (score -5):

just remove **await** from this line:

```
const json = await response.json()
```

Comment: That doesn't change a thing. That `await` is actually needed. `response.json()` is a `Promise`

Comment: `await` resolves the promise- which is the intended behavior. What you are trying to achieve by removing it?